# find and list all elements in dropdown selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

To loop through a dropwdown i want to list all elements in a dropdown so that i can let my code select each element one by one.

unfortunately the dropdown is not a select element, (if im not mistaken) so i cannot us something like :

```
 options = [x for x in select_box.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")]
```

I tried doing this by first opening the dropdown

```
Bedrijfsindeling_dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportViewer1_ctl09_ctl21_ctl01"]')
Bedrijfsindeling_dropdown.click()
time.sleep(1)
```

Then after the dropdown is open i want to find all elements in the dropdown menu

i tried doing this by using xpath

```
Parent = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportViewer1_ctl09_ctl21_divDropDown")
all_children_by_xpath = Parent.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*")
print(all_children_by_xpath)
print('len(all_children_by_xpath): ' + str(len(all_children_by_xpath)))
```

However, it looks like i only find 6 elements. The dropdown consists of (i guess, i did not count them. but it's way more than 6) around 50 different options.

Anybody know how i can find all different elements? Also, what would be the quickest and easiest way to loop through each element?

link used : https://www.arbeidsmarktcijfers.nl/Report/4

dropdown i want to find the elements for : " Bedrijfsindeling "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do what i want.

```
Bedrijfsindeling_dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportViewer1_ctl09_ctl21_ctl01"]')
Bedrijfsindeling_dropdown.click()
time.sleep(1)
Parent = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportViewer1_ctl09_ctl21_divDropDown")
all_children_by_xpath = Parent.find_elements_by_xpath(".//input[@id]")

for ids in all_children_by_xpath:
        print(ids.get_attribute('id'))
time.sleep(1)
Bedrijfsindeling_dropdown.click()
```

i'd love to hear your solution if someone however knows a better way or knows a way to easily loop through all id's

Comment: you can accept your own answer so that in future people can refer it.